# Building angular custom elements into separated bundles where all vendors (dependencies) are placing in a separate file

Tags: angular, build, web-component, custom-element

For example, I have 2 bundles with custom elements: **a.js**, **b.js**

For each element I have own compiler (a-main.ts, b-main.ts) which bootstraps the module I need (AModule.ts, BModule.ts).

**{a,b}.js** is result of: **runtime.js** and **main.js**.
Then I have **common.js**, which is result of **vendors.js** and **pollyfils.js** of each build of custom elements.

As result, I have 2 files with custom elements and 1 file with pollyfills and vendors with own module scope for each custom element (fst scope for a, scnd scope for b).

Is there any solution how I can exclude duplicated code of dependencies and angular core from **common.js**?

Answer (score 0):

On angular.json, change the vendorChunk from false to true.

```
"vendorChunk": true
```

This configuration will create a new vendor.js file with all library code.